# Custom Image section in Customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

So I have this Custom Section in the Customizer that controls the Feature Products on the Home Page. There all registered and so on but the problem I'm stuck on is when the client uploads one of the feature image I don't know how to make it update.

**functions.php** code I'm working with:

```
    // Customiser
function themeName_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting('feature_product_one', array(
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/featureProducts/product1.png',
        'transport'     => 'refresh',
        'height'        => 180,
        'width'        => 160,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('feature_product_two', array(
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/featureProducts/product1.png',
        'transport'     => 'refresh',
        'height'        => 180,
        'width'        => 160,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('feature_product_three', array(
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/featureProducts/product1.png',
        'transport'     => 'refresh',
        'height'        => 180,
        'width'        => 160,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('feature_product_four', array(
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/featureProducts/product1.png',
        'transport'     => 'refresh',
        'height'        => 180,
        'width'        => 160,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_section('feature_images', array(
        'title'           => __('Featured Products', 'themeRemax'),
        'description'     => __('Your 5 Feature Images on the Home-Page.'), 
        'priority'        => 70,
        'active_callback' => 'is_front_page',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'feature_product_one_control', array(
        'label' => __('Feature Product #1', 'themeRemax'),
        'section' => 'feature_images',
        'settings' => 'feature_product_one',
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'feature_product_two_control', array(
        'label' => __('Feature Product #2', 'themeRemax'),
        'section' => 'feature_images',
        'settings' => 'feature_product_two',
    )));  

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'feature_product_three_control', array(
        'label' => __('Feature Product #3', 'themeRemax'),
        'section' => 'feature_images',
        'settings' => 'feature_product_three',
    )));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'feature_product_four_control', array(
        'label' => __('Feature Product #4', 'themeRemax'),
        'section' => 'feature_images',
        'settings' => 'feature_product_four',
    )));     

}
add_action('customize_register', 'themeName_customize_register');
```

I've set the 2 products to have the same default image but when I go into the customizer and update `Feature Product #2` it doesn't update at all.

I know I need to add some code in the front-page inside the `<img>` tag but I don't know what :/

I have a feeling that what I have above is a long winded way to do things but it's what I got working, if there is an easy way then I would appreciate you pointing me in that direction :)

I appreciate any help

*Side Note*: My **front-page.php**:

```
<div class="featureImg">
    <img src="What goes here?" alt="Product 1">
    <img src="What goes here?" alt="Product 1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I did some research on the matter and I found a solution. Basically WordPress has this cool feature where you can call something called `get_theme_mod` so what I essentially did was add `get_theme_mod` inside my `<img> src`.

So this is what I changed my `<img>` tag to after finding out about `get_theme_mod`:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'customizer-option-name' ) ); ?>" alt="Product 1">
```

Basically what this did was it fetched the `$wp_customize->add_setting('customizer-setting-name')` and then outputted the content. Although I have found no way yet to put an `default-image` within the customizer but when I do I will update this post.

This is what my `customizer.php` file looks like now:

```
function themeName_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    // Add Settings
    $wp_customize->add_setting('customizer_setting_one', array(
        'transport'         => 'refresh',
        'height'         => 325,
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('customizer_setting_two', array(
        'transport'         => 'refresh',
        'height'         => 325,
    ));

    // Add Section
    $wp_customize->add_section('slideshow', array(
        'title'             => __('Slider Images', 'name-theme'), 
        'priority'          => 70,
    ));    

    // Add Controls
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'customizer_setting_one_control', array(
        'label'             => __('Slider Image #1', 'name-theme'),
        'section'           => 'slideshow',
        'settings'          => 'customizer_setting_one',    
    )));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'customizer_setting_two_control', array(
        'label'             => __('Slider Image #2', 'name-theme'),
        'section'           => 'slideshow',
        'settings'          => 'customizer_setting_two',
    )));    
}
add_action('customize_register', 'themeName_customize_register');
```